# Chromecast channel not starting channel after stop iOS

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

I am using Google cast new production api to stop the mediacontrolchannel through

`[mediacontrolchannel stop]`

It is stopping the session but when I try to start the stopped channel it gives me an error of 
INVALID_REQUEST .What could be the reason. Pausing And Playing a channel works fine but Playing after the channel has stopped is not working

Any help would be appreicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the iOS apis but if I draw on similarities with the Android APIs, the "stop" command also unloads the media on the receiver side, hence to start it again, you need to load the media again. You can use "pause" instead of "stop" if you are planning to start the playback again.